# How to generate XML in ORACLE 11g with reference to given XSD?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, xsd

I am learning to generate XML in Oracle 11g PL/SQL language.

I would like to generate XML depending on the data I get from the db tables, but at same time it should follow the structure and validate the XML with reference to the XSD I am provided with.

I have registered the XSD schema through `dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema` and generated the XML through `dbms_xmlquery.getXml` using dynamic script and then validated it by using `XMLTYPE.schemaValidate`.

But in my process the flow is creating XML first and then validating it with XSD, so due to this I may not be able to get correct structure and need to work on structure while generating XML.

Is there any way I can generate the XML by referencing the XSD I stored so that I don't miss out on structure and the XML only gets created if the result of referencing is valid?

Comment: XML and XML Schemas in Oracle is a big topic.  Have a look at the [Oracle XML DB Dev Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb05sto.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really generate xml based on a schema.
The best is probably to generate the xml into an xmltype variable and then validate this against the schema.

You can use the following plsql block (to be run as a script) as a starting point. 
Alter the query to use xml functions (XMLFOREST, XMLELEMENT, XMLATTRIBUTES) to generate the xmltype variable.

Once you have this inside l_xml you should be able to validate it against your schema. (Then I presume report the error if you need to or continue and process the xml as required)

My sample just pretty prints the xml and puts it in dbms output.

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
  l_error varchar2(4094);
  --
  l_xml xmltype;
  l_tmp varchar2(4096);  
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Start');

  --generate variable from query
  select xmlelement("this:root"
      ,xmlattributes(
        'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xmlns:xsi",
        'http://ic.ac.uk.relationshipvisualiser.app.data.InputData' as "xmlns:this"
      )
      ,xmlelement("this:subelement"
        ,'subelementValue'
      )
      ,xmlelement("this:subelement2"
        ,'subelementValue2'
      )
    )
  into l_xml
  from dual;  

  --todo Write code to validate l_xml against xsd schema

  --now output xml
  select XMLSERIALIZE(Document l_xml as CLOB INDENT SIZE = 2)
  into l_tmp
  from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_tmp);


  dbms_output.put_line('End');
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  l_error := NVL(SUBSTR(SQLERRM,0,990),'NULL');
  dbms_output.put_line(l_error || ':-' || NVL(SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE,0,3000),'NULL')); 
end;
```